# How to obtain products when a relationship meets the Laravel Eloquent condition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following relationship in the database, each table with its respective and related model.

[image]

I have products where each product has its recipe, which is composed of zero or more elements and the amount needed.

After this I have a warehouse table, where I have the current stock of the element, what I want is to obtain the products in which the amount needed in the recipe is less than the stock.

How could I obtain this data? it occurred to me to create a scope in the model products but I do not know how to perform the validation since they can be 0 or n elements in the recipe ?

**Controller**

```
Product::with('recipe')
            ->enableElements()->get();
```

**Model Product**

```
public function scopeEnableElements($query)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query from `Recipe` to `WareHouse` by relating the `element_id`.

Recipe model:

```
public function warehouses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\WareHouse::class, 'element_id', 'element_id');
}
```

WareHouse model:

```
public function recipes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Recipe::class, 'element_id', 'element_id');
}
```

Controller code:

```
Product::whereHas('recipes', function($q) {
    $q->whereHas('warehouses', function($query) {
        $query->whereRaw('WareHouse.stock > Recipe.count');    // use table names here, not model names
    });
})->get();
```

If you wanted to do it with a scope in the Recipe model:

```
public function scopeEnableElements($query)
{
    $query->whereHas('warehouses', function($query2) {
        $query2->whereRaw('WareHouse.stock > Recipe.count');    // use table names here, not model names
    });
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
Product::whereHas('recipes', function($query) {
    $query->enableElements();
})->get();
```